# MySQL, How can I count the amount something happens in a month, and display the sum beside month names?

Tags: mysql

I need to display 2 columns. First column should have the month name. Second column should show me how many times something was released within each month. e.g:

```
 Month     number_of_releases
 January        4
 March          9
 December       2
```

So far, I have this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTHNAME(date) AS 'Month',
    /*Here is where I need help!*/ AS 'number_of_releases'
    FROM table_name;
```

Comment: You really don't want to take the year into account as well?

Comment: No, I just needed months! Thanks for your concern though:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how you are calculating `number_of_releases`, it's hard to say for certain... but you probably want to group your table by monthname and use a suitable [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html) to yield the number of releases.

For example, to obtain a count of the number of records within each month:

```
SELECT   MONTHNAME(date) AS Month, COUNT(*) AS number_of_releases
FROM     table_name
GROUP BY Month
```

Comment: I would suggest something like `order by month(date)` so the months appear in natural order.  The result from this query will put the months in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thank you eggyal, that is exactly what I needed help with!

Comment: Also thanks Gordon, I will use that aswell to display it in natural order.